# Django server error: ImportError: No module named dal

Tags: python, django

I'm working with a Django server not coded by me. I have already installed all dependencies using `pip install -r requirements`, but when I'm trying to execute `manage.py` I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named dal
```

The solution should be something like `pip install dal`, but when I try it, I get another error: there is no `dal` module.

I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.9.8

**UPDATE**

My current INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #'dal',
    #'dal_select2',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'django_extensions',
    'rosetta',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'geoposition',
    'cities',
    'core',
    'api',
    'dal',
    'dal_select2'
)
```

Comment: You should look at your INSTALLED_APPS inside settings.py, maybe you forgot to place 'dal' in it.

Comment: Inside `INSTALLED_APPS`, `dal` appears the first one :(

Comment: I don't think than placing dal in first position is a good idea it should be after all standard django applications

Comment: Moved to last position. Same error.

Comment: Can you update your question with the INSTALLED_APP section from the settings.py?

Comment: Maybe you are using virtual environment and forget about activating it, before installing `dal`?

Comment: and don't forget to include  `dal_select2` inside your INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Updated. `dal` and `dal_select2` are inside

Comment: try this `pip install django-autocomplete-light` and let me know if it works

Comment: Check your enviornment site packages directory for example `env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`  to check whether dal and dal_select2 files exists.

Comment: Thanks @latsha, fixed!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to install django autocomplete light with `pip install dal`, but you should install it by typing `pip install django-autocomplete-light`