# Website fails to load after db data upload

Tags: python, django

The website I am working with is based on django v3.2.19 with a mysql v8.0.32 back end, in a windows 10 environment.  The database had limited data, so I updated the db from a backup of the same db set up on a different system (AWS, linux).

The website, up until an hour ago was up and running.  After the data upload, I was unable to start the server with 'python manage.py runserver'.  The stacktrace that is displayed ends with:

```
C:\Users\jw708\Documents\Gain\gain>python manage.py test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jw708\Documents\Gain\gain\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dal'
```

Several online sites suggested that 'dal' needs be installed.  The 'dal' is the first app listed in the INSTALLED_APPS list of the settings.py file from this django application.  Usually I see this error when I start manage.py from the wrong directory.  I think the error relates to inability fo find config files or other settings files, but I'm not sure.  I can drop the db and restart, but that is not desirable.

Has anyone seen this specific error before?  Anyone know how to resolve the issue?

Joe White
DFCI

The problem occurred after loading the db:

mysql -p -uroot db_name < backup_file_name

and then

python manage.py runserver

(Note: the output above is from python manage.py test.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django server error: ImportError: No module named dal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632830/django-server-error-importerror-no-module-named-dal)